# WooCommerce remove parent folder from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, woocommerce, permalinks

I have installed wordpress and WooCommerce in folder "blog" (not root directory), so URL of this WP is www.domain.com/blog/

Now when visiting e-shop, I am getting URL www.domain.com/blog/e-shop/
What I need is to rewrite URL of e-shop to www.domain.com/e-shop/ (remove "blog/" from URL)

So when user clicks "blog", he will be redirected to
www.domain.com/blog/

when "e-shop", redirect to
www.domain.com/e-shop/

How to do it? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move Wordpress to the root directory instead.

This will solve your `e-shop/` address issue; as for the blog, you can simply create a page in Wordpress, call it 'Blog', and then on the Settings -> Reading page in the Wordpress admin panel, set your new Blog page as the 'Posts Page'. This will move the blog back to `www.domain.com/blog` for you, without affecting the address of the e-shop.

If you have Wordpress installed under the `blog/` folder, everything that Wordpress does - including your blog and your Woocommerce setup - also have to be inside that folder.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem I can not move wordpress into root folder. Please, do you know any other solution?

Comment: Not really, other than installing Wordpress twice - once in the blog directory and once in the e-shop directory.